# Spinner on top with many other `UIView`

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to find why my spinner is not visible.

I have a custom `UIActivityIndicatorView`. I want to put it on the top of my custom `UITableViewCell`.

Here is my code:

```
[downloadingSpinner startSpinner];
```

Where `startSpinner` is

```
- (void) startSpinner{
  [self setHidden:NO];
  [spinner startAnimating];
}
```

When I call this `startSpinner` method, I can't see my spinner. I directly tried to solve my problem with this code:

```
[self.cellView bringSubviewToFront:downloadingSpinner];
```

Where `cellView` is the main view of my cell. 
I also tried this code:

```
downloadingSpinner.layer.zPosition = 1000;
```

I finally checked the subviews of my main view (`cellView`). I can see 14 views and le 13th is my custom spinner.

I tried to change the order on the storyboard like this:

[image: 1st try] [image: 2nd try]

I don't have any other idea to put this spinner on top.

Comment: What is the view hierarchy? Can you show a screenshot of the hierarchy in the storyboard or the code that you used to add it to the view.

Comment: I've just added 2 screenshots of what I've tried.

Comment: OK, the second one should just work. Have you tried doing something daft like setting a background colour of red or something. Also, check the tick box for "hide when not animating" and you don't need to hide or show anything.

Comment: Actually it's not visible when I've added manually my `UIScrollView`. 
I just tried with the background and removing all hide stuff. It's visible until this `UIScrollView` is added. Here is my code to add this scrollView `[self addSubview:self.backgroundImageView];` where `self` is my custom scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I simply add

```
[self.cellView bringSubviewToFront:downloadingSpinner];
```

just after I've added my custom `UIScrollView`. Thank you for your help and I hope this will help someone else.